# validate session in java ee project

Tags: java, spring, redirect, model-view-controller

I need to make a controller which first validates the session, and if it's not valid, it sends me back to login page. If it's valid I need to stay on the current page; I always get too many redirects; Is there a way to redirect from a void method? This is the method from the controller:

```
public String onLoad(HttpSession session){
    AngajatiBean ab=(AngajatiBean) session.getAttribute("myAng");
    session.setAttribute("forms",pas.getForms(ab));
    if(ab!=null)
        return "redirect:hello.htm";
    else
        return "redirect:here.htm";

}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention ..everything else is ok and myAng is sent when the login is made. i also have a logout page which invalidates sessions.

Comment: Use some library like [spring-security](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html) or [shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html) for this.

Comment: i saw something like that but i didn't understand exactly how to and i wouldn't want to ruin my configuration xmls. is there any other way to do it ? just from the controller ? maybe a function which can redirect without being returned from the controller ?

Comment: `Is there a way to redirect from a void method` what do you mean? You won't return a `String` from `onLoad` method?

Comment: i meant to change the function return type to void and redirect somehow from inside only if there is no data on current session

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to redirect from a void method?

Actually, you can implement `Filter`'s method `doFilter` in order to redirect users to login page when session expires.

```
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter{

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {       
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req=(HttpServletRequest)request;
        req.getSession().setAttribute("forms",pas.getForms(ab));
        if(req.getSession().getAttribute("myAng")==null){
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/here.htm").forward(request, response);
        }else{
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }    
    public void destroy() {}  
}
```

Then add this to your `web.xml` to configure your filter

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>FilterExample</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.stackoverflow.answer.RedirectFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>FilterExample</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/here.htm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```